# Pushing songs on android emulator internal storage

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard

I am creating a music application in which I want to load songs from both phone memory and sdcard. I have pushed some audio files on the sdcard of the emulator and it works perfectly fine. Now I want to push audio files on phone memory. For that I am trying to push file on "mnt" folder in DDMS but it throws error and fails to push.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: what is the error u r getting ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem may be because when creating the emulator you din't specify size for the emulator. In file explorer, check whether the sdcard folder under mnt direcctory has d-rwxr-x permission. If it doesn't have then create a new avd(Window -> AVD Manager). In the sdcard section, give 500 MB or so in Size attribute. Specify other attributes and click Create AVD button. Try pushing in then.

Comment: i want to store audio files on internal memory(phone memory) not on external memory(sdcard). I am able to push songs on sdcard folder but i want to store songs outside sdcard and emulator is not allowing to store songs.How should i store songs on phone memory ? The phone memory is of 1024MB and sdcard is of 1024MB.